# Using foreach to get the even numbers out of array c#

Tags: c#

I have this homework assignment where I have array called `myArr` with values `4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3` and I have to extract even numbers out of there and place them in `myOtherArray` and then printing them with foreach. I tried doing the code but I kinda got stuck since I know it won't work.

Here is my attempt:

```
int[] myArr = { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };

int num = 0;

int[] myOtherArr = new int[num];

for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
{
    if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        num++;
    
    }
}
```

`Num` is the counter to count how many even numbers are there, but right now I don't know how to save them into `myOtherArray` because I get the error that `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
{
     if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
          myArr[i] = myOtherArr[i];

     }
}
```

Right now I don't know how to do this. Please help I want to be ready for my exam comming soon.

Thank you all in forward for your answers.

Comment: Right now you're trying to overwrite the original array. Shouldn't you switch order to make a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
    int[] myArr = { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };
    
    var i=0;
    foreach (var item in myArr)
        if (item % 2 == 0) i++;
    
    var myOtherArr= new int[i];
    i=0;
    foreach (var item in myArr)
        if (item % 2 == 0) { myOtherArr[i] = item; i++; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try using Array.FindAll() built-in method to achieve this , instead of looping construct. Please try below code.

```
var myArr = new int[] { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };
var myOtherArr = Array.FindAll(myArr, v => v%2 == 0);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
int[] myOtherArr = new int[num]; // you initialize the array to 0 length.
```

Try this:

```
int[] myArr = { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };

int num = 0;



for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
{
    if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        num++;
    
    }
}

int[] myOtherArr = new int[num];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
{
     if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
          myOtherArr[j] = myArr[I];
          j++;
     }
}
```

Comment: `myOtherArr[i] = ` is incorrect, it should be *different* index, not `i` (note that `i` is in `0..myArr.Length` when `myOtherArr` should be in `0..num` range)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes sorry, I just copied and pasted OP's code, fixing now

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way because you don't have to figure out the length of the array.

```
int[] myArr = { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };
int[] myOtherArr;

List<int> cache = new List<int>();

//goes through each number in this array and stores the ones for that round in "num".
//If the number is "% 2 == 0" then it will be added to a list.
foreach (int num in myArr)
{
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        cache.Add(num);
    }
}


//the list is converted and stored in your array
myOtherArr = cache.ToArray();

//all numbers are displayed
foreach (int num in myOtherArr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

but you can also write it like this (I like to do this, for example).

```
int[] myArr = { 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 3, 3 };
int[] myOtherArr;

List<int> cache = new List<int>();

//goes through each number in this array and stores the ones for that round in "num".
//If the number is "% 2 == 0" then it will be added to a list.
foreach (int num in myArr)
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        cache.Add(num);

//the list is converted and stored in your array
myOtherArr = cache.ToArray();

//all numbers are displayed
foreach (int num in myOtherArr)
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```